# Serialization Exception in C#

Tags: c#, .net, serialization

Serialization exception occurs when I try to serialize a class in C#,
cause it holds a reference to a non serializable class.
The problem is that the class I want to serialize is very complicated,
and contains a lot of references to other complicated classes,
and I can't find the reference to the problematic class in this huge amount of code.
Is there a way to find out where is the property or filed with the non serializable class is?
Perhaps somewhere in the exception details? I didn't find something like it.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You should start examining the exception’s stack trace.

If necessary, configure Visual Studio to stop on any thrown exceptions (Debug -> Exception -> Check Thrown checkbox column for Common Language Runtime Exceptions)

That should stop Visual Studio at the exact place where the exception was thrown and that will give you a stack trace wich you can examine.

If that is not enough and depending on how your serializable classes are created, you can try running your assembly trough [sgen.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bk3w6240.aspx) to create another assembly responsible for the serialization.

sgen.exe has na option “/k” for keeping the source code. You can add this code to a project from where you should be able to breakpoint into it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to get the information from the exception by "catch 
(Exception exceptionObject) and wrapping the serialization 
call in a try block (opening a file in this example):

```
try 
{
    FileStream inputFileStream = 
      new FileStream(aSaveFileNameFullPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
}
catch (Exception exceptionObject) 
{
    displayStandardExceptionInfo(exceptionObject, "Could not open file " + aSaveFileNameFullPath);
}
```

---

displayStandardExceptionInfo() is defined as:

```
public static void displayStandardExceptionInfo(
  ref System.Exception anExceptionObject, ref string aStartText)
{
    string errMsg1 = 
      "Error: " + anExceptionObject.ToString() + "\n";
    string errMsg2 =
      "\n" + "Message: " + anExceptionObject.Message + "\n";

    string errMsg3 = "";
    if (anExceptionObject.InnerException != null)
    {
        errMsg3 = 
          "Extra info: " + 
          anExceptionObject.InnerException.Message +
          "\n";
    }
    string errMsg =
      aStartText + "\n" + "\n" + errMsg1 + errMsg2 + errMsg3;
    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(errMsg);
}
```

Comment: You could append the `InnerException.Message` in a (recursive/iterative) loop until there's no exception message left to add.